# Trying to Populate IE Input Box, Click Submit, then Retrieve a Value from IE

Tags: excel, vba, dom, excel-2010, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to automate the retrieval of domain name values from GoDaddy's valuation service located at: https://www.godaddy.com/domain-value-appraisal

I have done close to 400 manually but it is very tedious, error-prone, and it takes forever. I figured if I could create a VBA function in Excel 2010 then I could automate Internet Explorer. The IE version on the machine I would being this is IE 11.

I have tried several different suggested examples from various sites, including StackOverflow.com and I have not made any progress. I am stuck at how to populate the text box with a domain name from my spreadsheet. So what I did was just hard code a domain name for testing. I can whip up code that will loop through 400 rows later but right now I am trying to get just one to work.. I am messing up something with the IE DOM I think.

I cant even be sure that the rest of my steps are even coded correctly. The latest version of the code is below.

There are three steps to what I would like to automate:
Step 1: enter a domain name from my spreadsheet into the input box at https://www.godaddy.com/domain-value-appraisal
Step 2: click the "GoValue" button
Step 3: return the estimated value back to a cell on my spreadsheet.

The code is below. Thanks if anyone can identify what I have done incorrectly and how to proceed correctly.

```
Sub Try3()

Dim IE              As New InternetExplorer
Dim doc             As HTMLDocument
Dim objDomainIn     As HTMLInputElement
Dim objGoButton     As HTMLButtonElement
Dim objValueOut     As HTMLSpanElement

IE.Visible = True

'GO TO THE GODADDY VALUATION PAGE
IE.Navigate "https://www.godaddy.com/domain-value-appraisal"

'WAIT FOR THE PAGE TO LOAD
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.LocationName = "Free Domain Value and Appraisal Tool | What is your domain worth? - - GoDaddy"

Set doc = IE.document

'I WOULD LIKE TO DO THE FOLLOWING STEPS FOR SEVERAL HUNDRED DOMAIN NAMES. BUT FOR THIS EXAMPLE, HERE IS ONE OF NAMES:

'1) insert the domain name into the "domainToCheck" textbox
'2) click the "GoValue™" button
'3) scrape the Estimated Value from the result page

'SO TRANSLATING THOSE STEPS TO VBA I TRIED:

'STEP 1)
'THE INPUT TEXTBOX ON THE FORM:
'<input name="domainToCheck" class="domain-name-input searchInput form-control" aria-label="Enter a domain name" type="text" placeholder="Enter a domain name" value="">
Set objDomainIn = doc.all.getElementsByName("domainToCheck") '<----**** I AM STUCK HERE ***
objDomainIn.Value = "MPGBooster.com"



'STEP 2)
'BUTTON THAT NEEDS TO BE AUTOMATICALLY CLICKED (I added carriage returns because it was very long):
'<button class="btn btn-primary  submit    "
' type="Submit"
' data-eid="gce.sales.domain-value-appraisal.domain_search_marquee.domain_search_marquee_lp_module.button"
' data-creative-slot="e6a02371-14a2-4a21-b444-4aa0ae01b3b7"
' data-creative-name="domain-value-appraisal/Domain Search Marquee LP Module/Domain Search Block/Primary CTA"
' data-promo-name="domain_search_marquee.domain_search_marquee_lp_module.button8b002669-c11d-4913-881e-fe39fce24eab"
' data-promo-id="gce.sales.domain-value-appraisal."
' data-schema="add_promotion" data-tdata="module_id,e6a02371-14a2-4a21-b444-4aa0ae01b3b7^block_id,8b002669-c11d-4913-881e-fe39fce24eab^block_path,/ComponentSettings/GoDaddy/Sales/domain-value-appraisal/Domain Search Marquee LP Module/Domain Search Block/Primary CTA^campaign_name,^redpntcn,^redpntrid,^redpntcid,^redpntsn,^redpntrc,"
' value="GoValue™">GoValue™</button>

'CLICK "GOVALUE" BUTTON TO GET DOMAINS VALUE
Set objGoButton = doc.document.getElementsByClassName("input-group-btn")
objGoButton.click

'STEP 3)
'THE RETURNED HTML SHOWING THE DOMAIN ESTIMATED VALUE
'<span class="dpp-price price"><strong>$1,426</strong></span>
Set objValueOut = doc.getElementsByClassName("dpp-price price")
MsgBox "MPGBooster.com valued at: " & objValueOut.innerText

'CLEAN UP OBJECTS
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

First, getElementsByName is the property of the Document object.  Secondly, it returns a 0-based collection of elements.  Therefore, try the following instead...

```
Set objDomainIn = doc.getElementsByName("domainToCheck")(0)

objDomainIn.Value = "MPGBooster.com"
```

Alternatively, you can use the querySelector method...

```
Set objDomainIn = doc.querySelector("input[name='domainToCheck']")

objDomainIn.Value = "MPGBooster.com"
```

Note that getElementsByClassName also returns a 0-based collection of elements.  So you'll need to index accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! That got me over the first hurdle. The text is populated and the form submitted but for some reason the result doesnt appear via VBA automation. IF I do this manually I get the full estimate information that I am looking for. Any idea why its different when submitted via automation as apposed to manually?

Comment: After clicking the button and the new page loads, you need to assign the ie document to your variable again - - > Set doc = IE.document

Comment: Hi Domenic, I have done the but I am watching the actual window and its missing the entire section with the estimated value. Not sure if this is an IE problem (with GoDaddy) but that section is missing when I try it stand-alone IE. It works with Chrome and Firefox but not IE. Its very odd -- the Godaddy header and footer are there but nothing in between. :-/

Comment: @ONDEV, I think it is because GoDaddy is not so compatible with IE. If I do the steps without VBA automation, the estimate information section still can't show in IE. VBA automation only works in IE, you could use [Selenium Basic](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic) or [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to automate other browsers like Chrome, Edge and so on to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Yu Zhou - thank you for that lead. I am going to look into that!